# TikZ: complement mark at coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

I asked myself for the sake of interest: Is there possibly a possibility to add a `mark=<...>` to a `\coordinate`?

```
\documentclass[margin=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label={[mark=*, text=red,left]:A}] (A) at (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: The method

```
\foreach \P in {....} \draw[fill=white] (\P) circle (1.5pt);
```

is clear.

Comment: `\coordinate[label={[text=red,left]:\pgfuseplotmark{*}A}] (A) at (0,2);`? Or `\coordinate[label={[text=red,left]:A},label={[anchor=center,blue]:\pgfuseplotmark{*}}] (A) at (0,2);`? Please make your question clearer.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Ah, second methode could work.

Comment: Well, if course you can define a style like `\begin{tikzpicture}[cmark/.style={label={[anchor=center]:\pgfuseplotmark{#1}}}]
\coordinate[cmark=*,label={[text=red,left]:A}] (A) at (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Nice! The question should be rephrased “Is it possible to mimic MetaPost's `dotlablel` macro with Ti*k*Z?”. ;-)

Comment: @frougon The question is how much sense this makes as opposed to just using a node (like `node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]`). The latter has all the node anchors, i.e. if you connect it with an arrow, it looks good, but the plot mark stuff doesn't.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You're quite right, I replied without thinking enough... thanks for your great advice, as usual!

Comment: How can I use mark options here, maybe `mark options=  {fill=white, mark size=1.5pt}`

Comment: crosspost: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/25367/tikz-mark-bei-coordinate-erganzen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it is worth. This adds a plot mark and respects `mark options`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cmark/.style={append after command={plot[only marks,mark=#1] coordinates {(\tikzlastnode)}}}]
\coordinate[label={[text=red,left]:A},cmark={*,mark options={fill=white}}] 
(A) at (0,2);
\path (2,2) node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,draw,label={[text=red,left]:B}] (B){} ;
\draw[stealth-stealth] (A) to[out=90,in=90] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that I do not see any advantage compared to option `B` in which a node is used. Rather, I see a disadvantage since, if you connect either of them with an arrow, only the node knows the boundary, as illustrated. (Of course, in the node case you can connect to the center, too, by using `B.center` instead of `B` in the arc path.)